# Dart / Flutter. Child class can't access parent setter function

Tags: flutter, dart

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    Function _onChangeListener;

    set onChangeListener(Function value) {
        _onChangeListener = value;
    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    /// Some fancy stuff

    function testChangeListenerAccess() { 
        onChangeListener(testListener)/// error, The method onChangeListener is not defined.
    }

    function testListener() { 
    }

}

class SomeWidget {
   final ChildClass child = new ChildClass();

   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        child.onChangeListener(onChange); /// Error with .onChangeListener. The method onChangeListener is not defined.
    }

    void onChange(){
        /// do fancy stuff
    }
}
```

Looks like I can't call .onChangeListener for some reason. If I add it as a regular method to ParentClass, I can reference the new method.

To clear up what I mean above. If I add the following to ParentClass:

```
void onChangeListener(Function value){}
```

The call in SomeWidget#build will not have an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters are different from `void` functions.

```
child.onChangeListener = onChange;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you this is it, although technically it is child.onChangeListener = onChange;